# Cannot read C# object from view model while rendering cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have the following class defined in View model

```
public class config{
    public string Name{ get; set;}
    public string HtmlContent{ get; set;}
}
```

An object of the above class is returned using view in Index.cs and rendered using Index.cshtml

```
public ActionResult Index()
     {
     config res = new config();
     
     res.Name = "John";
     res.HtmlContent = "<h1>Hi @Model.Name </h1>";
     
     return View(res);
     }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<div id = "Header">@Html.Raw(@Model.HtmlContent)</div>
```

Output received:

```
Hi @Model.Name
```

Output Expected:

```
Hi John
```

Is there a way to read the C# object embedded inside the html tags?

Comment: You're trying to circumvent the Model View Controller paradigm. You are building the View in the Controller. So even if there was such a thing, you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it doesn't make much sense to try to cheat yourself. @Model  is not html tag, it is a net view engine helper. Try this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
            var model = new config();
            model.Name = "John";
            model.HtmlContent = $"<h1>Hi {model.Name} </h1>";

            return View(model);
}
```

it usually makes sense when you don't have any views in your project. For example, you can use it in your API controller

```
           var model = new config();
            model.Name = "John";
            var content = $"<h1>Hi {model.Name} </h1>";

            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = content,
                ContentType = "text/html",
            };
```